# Function works, function variable does not

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, closures, setinterval

I tried to move a timer variable into a closure, like this

```
var varEndAndStartTimer = (function() {
    var timer; // persisted in closure
    return function() {
        if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(doIt, 500);
    };
})();

var theTimer;
function startIt() {
    function endAndStartTimer() {
        if (theTimer) clearInterval(theTimer);
        theTimer = setInterval(doIt, 500);
    }
    endAndStartTimer();
}
```

If I call the function `endAndStartTimer`things works as I expect them to work. If I instead call `varEndAndStartTimer` something loops.

The code is of course a bit more complicated and I can't even find out exactly how it loops. But the only difference in the code is the difference above.

Should not these versions work exactly the same? (`varEndAndStartTimer` is defined at the time of the call to `startIt`.)

*UPDATE*
All the code above is inside an anonymous function which is just called once (in the declaration).

There is a link of the form `window["callStartIt"] = function() { startIt(); }` which may be called. I think it is called here, but I am not sure at the moment.

Perhaps a construct like that is not allowed?

Comment: For me (in node.js) they both behave the same. What do you mean "something loops"? You're setting an INTERVAL timer, not a one-shot. It's supposed to loop isn't it?

Comment: @quorve: Eh, yes. It is supposed to loop in time by the interval. That works. It is the same in both versions of the function for (re)starting the interval timer. The code run in `doIt` does some XMLHttpRequest calls and changes the document. All the code is not mine so I am not sure exactly what is done (other code may run in parallelt), but it works as expected if I do not use the function variable version.

Comment: I think we need to see more of the code. I created [**this plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ph11KMvAR8qR8VUz689h) to demonstrate that they both work the same as defined in your question, as pointed out by quorve.

Comment: @NanoWizard: Yes, perhaps, but I have no idea what code might be relevant here. I just can't find any way the two versions should differ. Though it looks like a possible race condition, of course. Perhaps I just have to dig deeper into it myself first. I appreciate your answers since I can then dismiss the possibility that I have done something obviously stupid here.

Comment: "plunker" was new to me. Seems convenient for editing.

Comment: Maybe if you expound upon what you mean by "something loops". What exactly is the difference in behavior you see?

Comment: @NanoWizard and quorve: I did something really stupid and your questions just made me realize it. I have to stop the interval timer when everything is done, of course. Ooooh. :-P Many thanks. Your questions helped me out!

Comment: To summarize: It might be a bad idea to hide the timer variable from `setInterval` in a closure. Sometimes. ;-)